# Choosing a Laptop

Tags: laptop

I'm a ECE student. I'm having trouble choosing the right laptop. My budget is between 500 to 1500 US dollars. I'm not interested in gaming. I'm fine with thick or bulky laptops. The main thing I am looking for is good performance for software an ECE student would need and a good life.

Edited:

Thanks alot for the response!

I don't have any resolutions or screen size preferences.

By good life I would want it to last for about 4 years at least.

Softwares that I would use would mainly be Matlab, Multism, Pspice, LabVIEW and maybe solid works.

Comment: Do you know what software you will be using? Can you define "good life"? Do you have a screen size/resolution preference? Any other details you can add that would help us?

Comment: That maybe solid-works, makes a **huge** difference in recommendations. Without that, a cheap $300 dollar laptop would probably suit your needs.